# Storybook and Tailwind dark-mode works in Document view but not in Canvas view

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook, darkmode

After setting up the `storybook-tailwind-dark-mode` add-on for Storybook (by following [these steps](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-tailwind-dark-mode)), my component is no longer displaying correctly in dark-mode in the Canvas view. The component displays correctly while in Document view and other components are displaying correctly in canvas view, so not every component has this issue.

The elements are visible for a split second before the page goes blank. When inspecting the page, I can see all of the elements are there, but they are just not visible.

The only difference to the HTML seems to be the `dark` class added to the `body` element.

Any ideas as to why the elements are no longer displayed would be greatly appreciated ⚡️

I've inspected the elements to see what could be causing the elements to not be displayed. I was expecting to see a change to `display:none` or an element that is in front of the other elements, causing them to be hidden, but it seems the only change is the `dark` class being added to `body`.

I've also looked at `./storybook/preview.js` and `./storybook/main.js` for anything suspicious but I haven't found anything that looks out of place.

Answer (score 1):

There was a modal `<div>` that had a `dark:bg-gray-800` class that was being overlayed over all of the other elements.

The modal was correctly set in light mode to show and hide according to when the modal was open/closed, but this conditional was not applied for dark mode, so the modal was always open, and hiding the other elements.